# Getting "incorrect program id for instruction" when attempting to create a token account after creating a mint

Tags: web3.js, spl-token

I have just started learning Solana and my first exercise is to build a script that can create a token and then create vault accounts for use on openbook market:

1. Create token

   - create & initialize mint account
   - create metadata account v3 (metaplex)
   - create associated token account
   - mint to associated token account
   - revoke mint authority
2. Create vault accounts for Openbook

   - create base vault account
   - create quote vault account
   - create token account for base vault account for the mint created in step 1
   - create token account for quote vault account for the mint created in step 1

### Create Token

```
import {
  ComputeBudgetProgram,
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  SystemProgram,
  Transaction,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  MINT_SIZE,
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction,
  createInitializeMintInstruction,
  createMintToInstruction,
  getAssociatedTokenAddress,
  getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint,
  createSetAuthorityInstruction,
  AuthorityType,
} from "@solana/spl-token";
import { createMetadataAccountV3 } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";
import { createSignerFromKeypair } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi";
import {
  fromWeb3JsKeypair,
  fromWeb3JsPublicKey,
  toWeb3JsLegacyTransaction,
} from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-web3js-adapters";
import { createUmi } from "@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults";

export const createToken = async ({
  connection,
  payer,
  mint,
  supply,
  decimals,
  metadata,
}: {
  connection: Connection;
  payer: Keypair;
  mint: Keypair;
  supply: number;
  decimals: number;
  metadata: { [key in string]: any };
}) => {
  const umi = createUmi(connection.rpcEndpoint);
  const umiKeypair = fromWeb3JsKeypair(payer);
  const umiSigner = createSignerFromKeypair(umi, umiKeypair);
  umi.identity = umiSigner;
  umi.payer = umiSigner;

  const associatedTokenAddress = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    mint.publicKey,
    payer.publicKey,
    false
  );

  const transaction = new Transaction();

  transaction.add(
    ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({
      units: 1_000_000,
    }),
    ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
      microLamports: 1,
    }),
    SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: mint.publicKey,
      space: MINT_SIZE,
      lamports: await getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(connection),
      programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    }),
    createInitializeMintInstruction(
      mint.publicKey,
      decimals,
      payer.publicKey,
      null,
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    ),
    toWeb3JsLegacyTransaction(
      await createMetadataAccountV3(umi, {
        mint: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mint.publicKey),
        mintAuthority: umiSigner,
        payer: umiSigner,
        updateAuthority: umiKeypair.publicKey,
        data: {
          name: metadata.name,
          symbol: metadata.symbol,
          uri: metadata.uri,
          sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
          creators: null,
          collection: null,
          uses: null,
        },
        isMutable: false,
        collectionDetails: null,
      }).buildAndSign(umi)
    ),
    createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
      payer.publicKey,
      associatedTokenAddress,
      payer.publicKey,
      mint.publicKey
    ),
    createMintToInstruction(
      mint.publicKey,
      associatedTokenAddress,
      payer.publicKey,
      BigInt(supply) * BigInt(10 ** decimals)
    ),
    createSetAuthorityInstruction(mint.publicKey, payer.publicKey, AuthorityType.MintTokens, null)
  );

  return sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [payer, mint]);
};
```

### Create Vaults

```
import {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  PublicKey,
  SystemProgram,
  Transaction,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  createInitializeAccountInstruction,
  ACCOUNT_SIZE,
} from "@solana/spl-token";
import { MarketAccounts } from "../types";

export const createVaults = async ({
  connection,
  payer,
  mint,
  quote,
  marketAccounts,
  vaultOwner,
}: {
  connection: Connection;
  payer: Keypair;
  mint: PublicKey;
  quote: PublicKey;
  marketAccounts: MarketAccounts;
  vaultOwner: PublicKey;
}) => {
  const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(ACCOUNT_SIZE);
  const transaction = new Transaction();

  transaction.add(
    SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: marketAccounts.baseVault.publicKey,
      space: ACCOUNT_SIZE,
      lamports,
      programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    }),
    SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: marketAccounts.quoteVault.publicKey,
      space: ACCOUNT_SIZE,
      lamports,
      programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    }),
    createInitializeAccountInstruction(marketAccounts.baseVault.publicKey, mint, vaultOwner),
    createInitializeAccountInstruction(marketAccounts.quoteVault.publicKey, quote, vaultOwner)
  );

  return sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [
    payer,
    marketAccounts.baseVault,
    marketAccounts.quoteVault,
  ]);
};
```

### Main Program

```
import "dotenv/config";
import { secretKey } from "../../secret.json";
import { supply, decimals, min_order_size, price_tick, metadata } from "../../config.json";

import { decode } from "bs58";
import { Connection, Keypair, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { createToken, createVaults, createMarket } from "../lib";
import { getVaultOwnerAndNonce } from "../utils/serum";

const main = async (connection: Connection) => {
  const payer = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(decode(secretKey)));

  const mint = Keypair.generate();
  console.log(`Generated mint account: ${mint.publicKey}`);

  const tokenSignature = await createToken({
    connection,
    payer,
    mint,
    supply,
    decimals,
    metadata,
  });
  console.log(`Token created successfully: ${tokenSignature}`);

  const quoteMint = new PublicKey(process.env.DEVNET_QUOTE_MINT!);
  const marketProgramID = new PublicKey(process.env.DEVNET_MARKET_PROGRAM!);
  const marketAccounts = {
    market: Keypair.generate(),
    requestQueue: Keypair.generate(),
    eventQueue: Keypair.generate(),
    bids: Keypair.generate(),
    asks: Keypair.generate(),
    baseVault: Keypair.generate(),
    quoteVault: Keypair.generate(),
  };
  const [vaultOwner, vaultOwnerNonce] = getVaultOwnerAndNonce(
    marketAccounts.market.publicKey,
    marketProgramID
  );
  const vaultSignature = await createVaults({
    connection,
    payer,
    mint: mint.publicKey,
    quote: quoteMint,
    marketAccounts,
    vaultOwner,
  });
  console.log(`Vaults created successfully: ${vaultSignature}`);

  //   const marketSignature = await createMarket({
  //     connection,
  //     payer,
  //     mint: mint.publicKey,
  //     mintDecimals: decimals,
  //     quote: quoteMint,
  //     quoteDecimals: 9,
  //     marketAccounts,
  //     marketProgram,
  //     minOrderSize: min_order_size,
  //     priceTick: price_tick,
  //   });
  //   console.log(`Market created successfully: ${marketSignature}`);
};

try {
  main(
    new Connection(process.env.DEVNET_RPC_HTTP!, {
      wsEndpoint: process.env.DEVNET_RPC_WSS!,
    })
  );
} catch (err) {
  err && console.error(err);
}
```

### Utils

```
export function getVaultOwnerAndNonce(
  marketAddress: PublicKey,
  dexAddress: PublicKey
): [vaultOwner: PublicKey, nonce: BN] {
  const nonce = new BN(0);
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-constant-condition
  while (true) {
    try {
      const vaultOwner = PublicKey.createProgramAddressSync(
        [marketAddress.toBuffer(), nonce.toArrayLike(Buffer, "le", 8)],
        dexAddress
      );
      return [vaultOwner, nonce];
    } catch (e) {
      nonce.iaddn(1);
    }
  }
}
```

### Problem

When running the main program, the createToken sequence runs fine and I get a valid signature. However the script fails when trying to send the transaction that creates the vaults: `SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: incorrect program id for instruction`.

```
Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success
Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]
Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success
Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]
Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount
Program log: Error: IncorrectProgramId
Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2928 of 799700 compute units
Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: incorrect program id for instruction
```

If I were to comment out the lines that generates the mint keypair and the token creation, and then explicitly specify a mint `const mint = new PublicKey("<mint account created from first run>")` the script runs fine.

It's as if the `Connection.sendAndConfirmTransaction` hasn't confirmed the initialise mint transaction yet and therefore the mint account hasn't been created yet?

Is there a way I can ensure the mint account from the first transaction is confirmed and ready to have token accounts created.

### Constrain

Mint creation and vault creation needs to be separate sequential transactions (the vault token accounts need to be created after the mint has been created).

Answer (score 0):

SMH! It's always the little things that get me. I tried to set the commitment value for the createToken method to `finalized`:

```
sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [payer, mint], {
  commitment: "finalized",
})
```

This fixed it. I'm not so sure why as the docs say the default commitment is `max` which I thought was an alias for `finalized`.